# How to use local (user) installed version of VIM? - Linux

Tags: vim

I have vim 7.0 on my server machine and I don't have root permissions. So, I have extracted Vim73 to my home directory and installed using the following command without having any errors.

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install
```

But still if I open vim it is showing the older version.

How can my .vimrc file read the latest version installed from local user (home)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the `PATH` variable to include the path to the locally installed `vim`. Or create an alias `alias vim = /path/to/local/vim`.

Comment: Thanks for replies guys.. Adding an alias with proper path solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add your home to your path:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

If vim installs shared libraries, you'll also need to add your local libs path to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib:$HOME/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Choose lib or lib64 depending on what's present on your system.

Alternatively, call the binary with its absolute path:

```
$HOME/bin/vim
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an alias in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`, ...

`alias vim="/path/to/your/vim"`